# SwiftUI - button added has text auto-capitalized and is tappable in the whole view

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a view using SwiftUI. Here is the basic structure:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(notifications!, id: \.self) { notification in
            if let text = NotificationManager.shared.notificationText(notification: notification) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: Constants.VStack.spacing) {
                    HStack {
                        if notification.successfullyUploaded == false {
                            Image(systemName: Constants.Images.failure).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.alert))
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: Constants.Images.success).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.success))
                        }
                        Text(text).font(.system(size: Constants.FontSize.standard))
                    }
                    let secsAgo = notification.timeStamp?.timeIntervalSinceNow
                    if let secsAgo = secsAgo {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(getTimeString(secsAgo: secsAgo))").font(.system(size: Constants.FontSize.timeStamp)).foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.blue))
                            
                            if notification.successfullyUploaded == false {
                                
                                Spacer()
                                Button {
                                    print("Test")
                                } label: {
                                    Text("Amend submitted details").autocapitalization(.none)
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }.onDelete(perform: delete)
    }.cornerRadius(Constants.VStack.cornerRadius)
    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: Constants.Shadow.radius, x: Constants.Shadow.x, y: Constants.Shadow.y)
    .frame(width: Constants.VStack.width, height: Constants.VStack.height, alignment: .center)
}
```

I'm having trouble with the button I am trying to add. So essentially, this needs to be placed to the right hand side of the view and only this button should be tappable.

What I'm getting are 2 things I don't want:

1- the text is showing in all caps (hence why I tried adding `.autocapitalization(.none)`

2- the entire view reacts to the tap event when I actually only want to button itself.

Here is a screenshot of the view as it currently is:

[image]

Wherever I tap in the list item the print statement is triggered.

Comment: Is this on macOS, iOS? Which version of all used? Would you provide minimal reproducible example? (there is nothing bad in provided code).

Comment: sorry yes this iOS and I'm using a min version of 13.0